# Most efficient method to box/unbox multidimensional primitive arrays

Tags: java, algorithm

Is this most efficient method to box/unbox multidimensional primitive arrays in Java without using an external library?

```
private Float[][] toFloatArray(float[][] values)
{
   Float[][] objArray = new Float[values.length][values[0].length];

   for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < values[0].length; j++)
      {
         objArray[i][j] = values[i][j];
       }
   } 

   return objArray;
}
```

What's the most efficient using an external library?

Comment: Hadn't thought of that, but are you aware of a solution with less code?

Comment: BTW, you're not (un)boxing arrays, but array elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I'd do it that way. It will fail if the array isn't really "rectangular". I'd do something like:

```
private Float[][] toFloatArray(float[][] values)
{
   Float[][] objArray = new Float[values.length][];

   for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
   {
      objArray[i] = new Float[values[i].length];
      for (int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++)
      {
         objArray[i][j] = values[i][j];
      }
   } 

   return objArray;
}
```

You *might* be able to micro-optimize by removing intermediate array accesses:

```
private Float[][] toFloatArray(float[][] values)
{
   Float[][] objArray = new Float[values.length][];

   for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
   {
      float[] subSource = values[i];
      Float[] subDest = new Float[subSource.length];
      objArray[i] = subDest;
      for (int j = 0; j < subSource.length; j++)
      {
         subDest[j] = subSource[j];
      }
   } 

   return objArray;
}
```

... but I wouldn't be surprised to find out that good JITs can optimize anyway. (Possibly not for the source array, which could be changing behind the scenes, of course...)

Comment: The JVM can assume that the source array doesn't change behind the scenes since there's a distinct lack of thread synchronization.

Answer (score 3):

No magic here:  That is how apache-commons does it when you use their library:

```
public static short[] toPrimitive(Short[] array) {
    if (array == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (array.length == 0) {
        return EMPTY_SHORT_ARRAY;
    }
    final short[] result = new short[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        result[i] = array[i].shortValue();
    }
    return result;
}
```

[source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/lang/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.java?view=markup)